# Is there a time limit for how long SELECT FOR UPDATE locks the rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using `select_for_update` in Django these days which generate `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statements and I'm wondering roughly how long MySQL keeps the lock. Is there a timeout somewhere?

Comment: locks are held until you release them, or the connection is closed, allowing mysql to clean up. there's timeouts that can be applied for OTHER users waiting on the locked records.

Comment: @MarcB So if I do something dumb that ends up locking the rows for a few hours, everyone else is doomed? Scary, better use with care then. :)

Comment: pretty much. it'd be a Very Bad Thing is a db server could arbitrarily break locks. locks are used to ensure consistency between mutiple parallel users - if a record gets unlocked when it shouldn't, then there's no way to guarantee consistency.